# How can I "check in" at a hotspot?

Tags: watch-dogs

Watch Dogs has the ability to "check in" at various locations throughout the game, which provides perks and some online integration.

The first of such locations that I've arrived at is the Lighthouse. I was greeted with a tutorial that discusses using the app to check in at these hotspots but when I try and use the app on my phone to check in at the lighthouse I end up caught up in a bunch of screens detailing the current mayor of the lighthouse along with a bunch of other options that say I have to check in first.

I have tried setting waypoints using the GPS to the check in location but since I'm on the island with the lighthouse on it these are doing absolutely nothing.

How can I "check in" at a hotspot? What am I missing?

Comment: The sudden surge in the number of "Watch-Dogs" related questions. Seems like everyone in the world has it.

Comment: Is 13 questions considered a lot? Considering 5 of those are troubleshooting, I wouldn't call it a lot. It is quite a popular game after all.

Comment: @Chippies I know, but in such a short amount of time? The game was only released this morning. At least for me it was...

Comment: @DavidToh For much of the world, it came out on Tuesday.

Comment: @DavidToh. Also, Watch_Dogs is a high-profile game (aka. Triple-A game), like Assassin's Creed or GTA. It's pretty normal for high-profile games to have lots of questions pop up during the first week since release.

Comment: @DavidToh the game was officially released on May 27th and some have got their preorders early and it has been available through less legit means as early as May 22nd, so it's not a short amount of time at all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find a square plate with a check mark on it, it's shown on the minimap as well. It could be either on a wall or the ground.

When you find it, you have to walk to it and press <kbd>E</kbd> if you're using keyboard or <kbd>Y</kbd> if you're using a gamepad. Additionally, you can check-in from distance by pressing middle mouse button or <kbd>Up</kbd> on a gamepad.

Doing this will "check in" and show you some information about the spot.

[image: keyboard controls]
[image: xbox360 controls]

Comment: It's up on the Xbox 360 DPad for me.

Comment: It shouldn't be, are you using a non-default layout?

Comment: It's also up on Playstation controllers

Comment: @Chippies no, I'm using the standard layout. It's always been up. Are you using a non standard layout?

Comment: @Seiyria I just checked and found out something I hadn't noticed. You can check in from distance by pressing up on d-pad, or Y when you get close to it. I always used the Y option.

Comment: @Chippies I see. I usually just get in range and hit up, instead of finding the pad. I get it now.

Answer (score 10):

On PS4 and PC if you're close enough to those square plates, a HUD message will tell you to check in by pushing <kbd>Up</kbd> on a D-Pad (for consoles or PC with gamepad) or <kbd>MOUSE3</kbd> (for PC).

That way you can check in without even knowing where those plates are.

Comment: edited the answer so that it would also give an answer for PC version of the game. +1 for a correct and easy answer

Comment: The only problem with that is that if you for some reason miss the prompt, it goes away and you have to re-enter the area to bring the prompt up again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a grey square with a check mark in it and "activate" that. Sometimes it's on a wall, but I've also found it on the ground next to a gate. Don't forget to collect any gifts that are there!